# Android - testing on tablet.Which tablet is the best to test?

Tags: android, tablet

Which tablet do you recommend me for testing android applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motorola XOOM and Samsung galaxy TAB is best tablet.

Answer (score 1):

The ASUS Transformer is doing me well.

Answer (score 1):

If you test a very complicated application, you should use faster tablet like Samsung Galaxy Tab. Otherwise you can use some cheaper tablet like [these](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p5197.m570.l1311&_nkw=android%20tablet&_sacat=See-All-Categories)

Answer (score 0):

from my point of view samsung GALAXY Tab 10.1 is best .