# Android ADK Supported Device List

Tags: android, adk

While searching for Android ADK supported devices, I came across developers expressing the concern that although their device (smartphone or tablet) runs either Android 2.3.4 or 3.1, however, the ADK does not work.

So I would like to know the list of devices which support Android ADK.

I request the readers to add to the devices which they found works fine with Android ADK.

Note: I have seen another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425359/android-testing-on-tablet-which-tablet-is-the-best-to-test) which is meant only for Android ADK tablets, where as my question is about generic devices.

Comment: Typically, lists of objects or programs which support specific features are better kept on Wikipedia. They've got fantastic table support for different sorts of comparisons and by nature of reaching a far larger audience, are more likely to be up-to-date.

Comment: @sarnold, agree 100%. I will explore and add a WikiPedia page if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Let me start with a [link](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2919&param=en546070) which I found lists few Android ADK supported devices: